# Adding hundreds of thousands of entities to Datastore within minutes

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

The docs on Datastore talk about possible limitations with respect to **updating** entities of an entity group and frequently **updating** single entities.

Is it safe to assume, that **just adding** hundreds of thousands of entities within a short amount of time will not constitute a problem?﻿

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the entities are not in an entity group sith a parent, yes its safe to assume thst you can. Only if they have a parent you will have a write limitation of sprox. One per second.

Comment: Thanks, Zig! Do you have any concrete first-hand experience on write throughput with respect to massive inserts of ancestor-less entities? Or a link to a reference case? (I'm also in touch with Google but it would be very interesting!)

Comment: Yes I do. Also look at the docs you will find no limitations on ancestor-less. You can read or write as much as you can, google guarantees scalability of the datastore except on ancestor entities because they are on the same tablet and physical server thus google cant distribute those, hence the 1write per sec on those.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is safe to insert entities as long as they don't belong to a single entity group and they don't have same key name. See an excerpt from [GAE docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities)

> Note: The Datastore API does not distinguish between creating a new
>   entity and updating an existing one. If the object's key represents an
>   entity that already exists, the put() method overwrites the existing
>   entity. You can use a transaction to test whether an entity with a
>   given key exists before creating one. See also the
>   Model.get_or_insert() method.

The limitation is on writing to a single entity group. Entity groups are formed as follows:

- Every entity is in its own entity group
- An entity and all its descendents are in the same entity group

The limitation is about 5 writes per second as mentioned in the article about [Sharding Counters](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters).